# How to pass a block to a yielding thread in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, yield

I am trying to wrap my head around Threads and Yielding in Ruby, and I have a question about how to pass a block to a yielding thread.

Specifically, I have a thread that is sleeping, and waiting to be told to do something, and I would like that Thread to execute a different block if told to (ie, it is sleeping, and if a user presses a button, do something besides sleep).

Say I have code like this:

```
window = Thread.new do 

  @thread1 = Thread.new do
    # Do some cool stuff

    # Decide it is time to sleep
    until @told_to_wakeup
       if block_given?
         yield
       end
       sleep(1)
    end

  # At some point after @thread1 starts sleeping, 
  # a user might do something, so I want to execute
  # some code in @@thread1 (unfortunately spawning a new thread
  # won't work correctly in my case)

end
```

Is it possible to do that?

I tried using @@thread1.send(), but send was looking for a method name.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: It sounds like you need an event loop. Look at using [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Queue.html) to handle signalling threads.

Comment: I took a quick look at Queue, but it doesn't look like the block will execute in thread1. In this case, I basically need thread1 to execute the block I pass it, anything else executing the block and it doesn't work correctly (all tied into how thread1 is being used in other parts of the code)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple worker thread:

```
queue = Queue.new

worker = Thread.new do
  # Fetch an item from the work queue, or wait until one is available
  while (work = queue.pop)
    # ... Do something with work
  end
end

queue.push(thing: 'to do')
```

The [`pop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Queue.html#method-i-pop) method will block until something is pushed into the queue.

When you're done you can push in a deliberately empty job:

```
queue.push(nil)
```

That will make the worker thread exit.

You can always expand on that functionality to do more things, or to handle more conditions.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look into this. 

I was playing around with the code, and it still doesn't quite do what I need.

Here is what I have: https://repl.it/repls/TroubledPunyAdmins

The problem is Task1 doesn't stop and let Task2 execute, Task1 is still sleeping.

For a little more context, Task1 is executing based on a user action (ex: a button press) and it is waiting for another button press. However something outside of the UI can trigger actions/changes, and it won't show the user what is happening if the original thread isn't running the code.

Comment: Two things to consider. First, steer towards the [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) design pattern and have your worker loop perform short, quick actions that don't block or stall for extended periods of time. Introducing a `sleep` in there causes it to stop processing other events, and this is bad. Fire off background threads or use timers if that's necessary.

Comment: Secondly, always, **always** avoid slinging around arbitrary chunks of code as strings that get passed to `eval`. In Ruby it's very easy to pass in a Proc instead: `queue.push(-> { do ... stuff. })` where the internals are actual Ruby code, not a string. This also helps with binding problems as you can have a proper closure, something not possible with a string.